# Pop up Selected images of a gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

[image]

I have an android application using gallery.Each gallery item consist of an imageview along with a textview to show the caption of image.This screen also contains some other components like a header view, footer view etc...Each gallery item is showed for a fixed time.

Now i want to pop up the gallery item if the user tap on an item.(Image and its caption).This view will float on the screen as shown in figure.how can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an activity with a layout of all your requierd components and then use the following code in your manifest for that activity

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivityName"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

where `AppTheme` is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: put it in styles.xml in `/res/values/` folder